# Change data- of the button that has a certain data- attribute inside same parent

Tags: jquery

I have this html structure:

```
<form class="d-flex justify-content-between mt-auto">
   <select class="form-control flex-grow-1" id="my-id">
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
        <option>Option 3</option>
   </select>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ml-1 mr-4">Button 1</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ml-1 mr-4" data-button-id="some-id" data-type="pickme">Button 2</button>
</form>
```

This is repeated a couple of times on my page, with different ids of course.

Now, I want to change the `data-button-id` whenever the select changes inside the same form. So basically, I want to get the button that has `data-type` 'pickme' and is in the same parent, and then change its `data-button-id`.

Here's what I tried:

```
$("select").change(function() {
   if(this.id=="my-id")
   {
      $(this).parent().$('button').find("[data-type='pickme']").data("data-button-id","somethingnew");
   }
});
```

... but I get: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).parent(...).$ is not a function`.

Comment: no need for the extra `$(button)` - `$(this).parent().find("button[data-type='pickme']")`

Comment: The `if` conditional in the change event handler is also odd.  If the only logic is for that specific element, bind on that element.

Comment: @Taplar not sure what you mean... could you elaborate? I want to change the data-button-id to a different value depending on the select that was changed.

Comment: `$('select').change(function (){  if (this.id == 'my-id') { ... } })`  <= you are only doing logic if the id is 'my-id'.  So why not bind on that element, and get rid of the if?

Comment: Fair point. This code will be appended with other `else if(this.id=="my-other-id")`s though...

Comment: @Taplar *"This is repeated a couple of times on my page, with different ids of course."* - of course, checking the `id` isn't the best way to handle this, but that wasn't the question (and your comment was just an observation on the provide code, of course).

Comment: Yeah, I missed that part.  And yeah, all that is just a side note.

Comment: OK, thanks anyway for the advice. Always happy to learn :)